# References with mathematical formulation of the learning problem with neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, lstm

I'm a novice at using neural networks.
I've developed a good solution for a problem using a neural network that has two branches: a feed-forward network and a bi-LSTM, that receives different kinds of inputs. After, the outputs of these two branches are concatenated in a block of layers.

I'm writing a paper for presenting our solution. However, I don't know how to formulate in a mathematical way the learning problem in the context of our architecture.

I'm looking for references that explain how can I do that.

Best regards.

Comment: You have an input (features), an output, and a regression model (the neural networks) connecting them. What more do you need?

Comment: I'm not sure. The reviewer of the paper just asked for a mathematical formulation of the problem.

Comment: What do you see in the articles that you reference?

Comment: @Dave. Most of them are just showing block diagrams of the networks, without any mathematical characterization.

Comment: @Dave. I have used a block diagram in my paper, as well.

Comment: What is "a mathematical formulation of the learning problem"? Can you provide an example of what the reviewer is asking for in the context of a simpler/well-known model?